# boost::property_tree::ptree::iterator does define operator+

Tags: boost

std::XXX::inerator always support operator+, such as

```
const string s = "abcdef";
cout << *(s.begin() + 3);//output d
```

But ptree doesn't support operator+.

```
ptree p = root.get_child("insert");
//I want to directly goto the 3rd child.
auto iter = p.begin()+3;//error
```

I know I can use a for loop to do this. But I wonder if there is a more grace way to do this?

Comment: From the docs (my emphasis): "The Property Tree library provides a data structure that stores an arbitrarily deeply nested tree of values, indexed at each level by some key. Each node of the tree stores its own value, plus an ordered list of its subnodes and their keys. The tree allows easy access to any of its nodes ***by means of a path,*** which is a concatenation of multiple keys." I imagine you lose quite a bit of flexibility if you start referring to things as absolute or relative indices.

Comment: I have to do this. <bussinessList><bussiness><\bussiness><bussiness><\bussiness><bussiness><\bussiness><\bussinessList>

Answer (score -2):

I achieved this by:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
  void advance (InputIterator& it, Distance n);
```

[C++   stl advance document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/)

```
auto iter = p.begin();
advance(iter, 3);
```